# No operator ">=" matches these operands error in c++ when using while loop

Tags: c++

Here is the code

```
int main()
{
    int x;
    while((cin >> x) >= 2){
      cout<<"Greater than 2";
    }
}
```

and I am using these preprocessor directives

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ios>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>

using std::cout;  using std::cin;
```

I am getting error in the while loop, it says this:

```
no operator ">=" matches these operands -- operand types are: std::basic_istream<char, std::char_traits<char>> >= int
```

I am new to c++

Comment: `(cin >> x)` returns `cin`, not `x`. You might want `while((cin >> x) && x >= 2)` if you want to do everything in the comparison line. (Also, strictly speaking, those `using` statements aren't preprocessor directives, only the `#include`s are.)

Comment: This worked! I don't understand why I can't compare cin >> x directly using > 2 operation, can you please explain that part or refer som resource which I can read to get better understanding? Thanks

Comment: The compier error is clear: `no operator ">=" matches these operands -- operand types are: std::basic_istream<char, std::char_traits<char>> >= int
`, the type of `cin >> x` is `std::basic_istream<char, std::char_traits<char>>`, you can't compare it with `int`

Comment: @RealSlimShady `cin >> x x` returns `cin` as mentioned above. It is equivalent to `cin.operator>>(x)` which puts a value read, into x and returns the istream object `cin`. This can be easily seen when considering the line `cin >> a >> b`. It wouldn't make sense to write `a>>b`, but the above code is correct, as `cin>>a` returns `cin` instead of `a`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the while condition, you are comparing **cin>>x** and **2**.

I believe you wanted to check for conditions where x>= 2. But, in your code,  the compiler is comparing the output of **cin>>x** with **2**. As the output of the **cin** operator is not INT, hence you are getting the error.

For more information on this, you can refer to: https://devdocs.io/cpp/io/cin

As far as correcting the code is concerned, try **while( cin>>x && x>=2)** because here the compiler will first execute the **cin** and then it will execute the comparision.

Answer (score 1):

Please change the code as below so that reading from input stream is separated from integer comparison.

```
int main()
{
    int x;

    while(true)
    {
        std::cin >> x;
        if(x > 2)
        {
            std::cout << "Greater than 2";
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << "Lesser than or equal to 2";
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

You are getting the error because Integer value cannot be compared with instance of Input Stream. Please note that `cin >> x` returns cin (istream object) but not value you read (integer in your case).